Extract a table from docx using spire.doc in Python and fixedlayout
I need to extract all the tables from a word (docx) document, but I need to know from which page the table is.
I have been able to extract the images iterating over the pages (to do so, I am using the FixedLayoutDocumentmodule from spire.doc in Python).
This is the code snippet:
doc = spd.Document()
doc.LoadFromFile(documents_path)

layoutDoc = spd.FixedLayoutDocument(doc)
pages_count = doc.GetPageCount()
# Access the first page of the document
    
for page in range(pages_count):

    layoutPage = layoutDoc.Pages[page]

    # Traverse through each row in the first column of the first page
    for i in range(layoutPage.Columns[0].Lines.Count):
        line = layoutPage.Columns[0].Lines[i]
        # Get the paragraph of the current line
        paragraph = line.Paragraph

        # Traverse through the child objects in the paragraph
        for j in range(paragraph.ChildObjects.Count):
            obj = paragraph.ChildObjects[j]
            # Find the images
            if isinstance(obj, spd.DocPicture):
                picture = obj
                # Append the image data to the list
                image_bytes = picture.ImageBytes
               
                images.append(
                    {'img_bytes': image_bytes,
                     'in_page': page}
                )

But for the tables I am not able to reproduce this behaviour...
DO you know how I could achieve to extract (at least) the page in which we can identify the tables?
